# How to convert DMS to Radian with a given format : DD-MM-SS in python

Tags: python

I would like to know how to convert DMS (degrees, minutes, seconds) to Radians from a given format, DD-MM-SS.

The solution for `print (DMStoRAD(47-39-28))` should be 0.831785.

Comment: @user3481644 In its current state, the question is not even a programming question. It is a math question. It shows zero effort, and is thus not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I disagree, although it is mostly math, there is a programming aspect for the conversion of three integer values, apparently represented as a string, into a single real value. If its current state is the issue, then perhaps somebody should fix it, like they do in the EE SO. We need to remember that not all programmers have the same skill level, nor can ask questions exactly as SO likes them. But, if you insist, his question could be moved to the SO site focused on mathematics.

Comment: @user3481644 IMHO, the programming part only becomes relevant *after* you know how to perform the necessary math. Right now, the question is basically "do all the research for me, and provide me an implementation". That is off-topic (both for lack of effort and being unfocussed).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I would agree if it weren't for the phrase "from a given format, DD-MM-SS". It's hard to determine exactly if the OP knows how to do the conversion since he did provide a sample problem, which, I admit, could have been provided by his teacher. Most of the questions I read could be in that category. And we don't know the OP's skill level. Perhaps SO needs to have a skill level attribute - instead of a blind down vote, there would be skill-down-vote and such questions are filtered out of highly skilled SO members' view. SO is like a street-name sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy

def dms_string_to_radians(dms_string):
    degrees = numpy.sum(numpy.fromstring(dms_string, sep='-') * 
            [1.0, 1/60.0, 1/3600.0])

    return numpy.radians(degrees)

print dms_string_to_radians('47-39-28')
```

outputs:

```
0.831785136406
```

as expected.

Or, if you don't like to use Numpy and wish to stick with standard libraries:

```
import string, math

def dms_string_to_radians(dms_string):

    dms = [float(x) for x in string.split(dms_string, '-')]
    degrees = sum(
            [scale * val for scale, val in zip([1.0, 1/60.0, 1/3600.0], dms)])

    return math.radians(degrees)

print dms_string_to_radians('47-39-28')
```

This outputs the same as the first.

I changed the function name because I couldn't bring myself to use your naming convention ;)

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately i got an error: NameError: global name 'fromstring' is not defined I dont know what the problem is here :\

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def DMS2Rad(D, M, S):
    return ((D+M/60+S/3600)/180*3.141592654)
```